# Rendering same vertex-array in different modes

Tags: rendering, webgl

here is my vertex array I am using:

```
vertices = [
    -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
     0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
    -0.5,  1.0,  0.0,
     0.5,  1.0,  0.0,
     1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
     1.0,  0.5,  0.0,
     0.0,  0.5,  0.0,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.0,
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.0,
    -1.0,  0.5,  0.0,

    -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    -0.5,  0.0,  0.0,
     0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
     0.5,  0.0,  0.0,
     1.0,  0.0,  0.0,

    -1.0, -0.5,  0.0,
     0.0, -0.5,  0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.0,
     1.0, -0.5,  0.0,
     1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
     0.0, -1.0,  0.0,
     0.5, -1.0,  0.0,
    -0.5, -1.0,  0.0,
    -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
];
```

In a html-select I want to select a rendering mode and use it inmy `drawScene`-method:

```
var renderModeSelector = document.getElementById("renderModeDropDown");
var selectedRenderModeValue = renderModeSelector.options[renderModeSelector.selectedIndex].value;

switch (selectedRenderModeValue) {
    case "0":
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
        break;
    case "1":
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
        break;
    case "2":
        gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
        break;
    default:
        console.log("No rendering mode selected.");
}
```

1. Case '0' is supposed to draw the points which works fine

   [image]
2. Case '1' should draw a filled rectangle, with the shader below. Unfortunately it is messed up, see also in the picture below.

   Fragment shader:

   ```
   precision mediump float;

   varying vec4 vColor;

   void main(void) {
   gl_FragColor = vColor;
   }
   ```

   Vertex-shader:

   ```
   attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
   attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

   uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
   uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

   varying vec4 vColor;

   void main(void) {
   gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
   vColor = aVertexColor;
   gl_PointSize = 5.0;
   }
   ```

   [image]
3. And finally in case '2' it is supposed to draw only the outlines, which also does not work as expected, see below.

   [image]

So I wonder if it is possible to meet my requirements while using one vertexPositionBuffer. Should I maybe create another vertexPositionBuffer or can I just change mine "on the fly", before rendering?

Comment: You need only 4 vertices for all cases. `1:-`  You could easily use nested `for loops` to draw the `case 0`. You could get 4 end points by simple maths and then draw lines and triangles between them for `case 1`, `case 2` respectively. `2:-` Or you can have the end points and then divide them up for `case 0`. I would probably do the latter.

Comment: Your data is off. You do not account for winding rules.

Comment: @ritwiksinha Yeah the thing is I want it to be that many vertices.

Comment: @joojaa What do you mean by "data is off"? I know some of the points are not in the right order I changed that, It does not fix the issue.

Comment: @Käsebrot Why don't you use section formula to calculate the points in between the 4 vertices, namely $(1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1), (1, -1)$

Comment: For doing the solid part, you're better off using something like TRIANGLE_STRIP. You will need topology information in the form of an indice buffer which tells the GPU how to interpret your list of points as a strip. Vertices will need be reused for TRIANGLE_STRIP so the indice buffer is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shaders are fine, the problem is topological, that is the way the vertices are connected to create triangles.

For cases 1 & 2: You cannot really draw a grid of points in this mode (`GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`) as vertex 0 (the top left one) will be used in every triangle, as well as other issues. You should be using Triangle/Line strips, although these aren't so straightforward as some vertices are shared between each row.

For example, imagine you have vertices arranged like so:

> 0 1 2
>
> 3 4 5
>
> 6 7 8

You would draw strips by sending the above vertices in the following order:

> 0,3,1 (outputs triangle 0,1,3)
>
> 4,    (outputs triangle 1,3,4)
>
> 2,    (outputs triangle 1,2,4)

etc...

This you can do in code by scanning across 1 row of vertices and including the vertex on the next row for every other vertex.

e.g.

```
int numColumns = 5;   // As per your example..
int numRows = 5;
int vertexOffset = 0;
int vertexSize = 3;          // 3 floats per vertex
int nextRow = numColumns * vertexSize;   

// This loop is for each row-strip, which requires 2 vertex rows..
for(int j = 0; j < numRows - 1; j++) {

    // Inner loop sends vertices for each row-strip
    for(int n = 0; n < numColumns; n++, vertexOffset += vertexSize) {
       glVertex3fv(vertices + vertexOffset);            // Current row
       glVertex3fv(vertices + vertexOffset + nextRow);  // Row below
    }
    // This is special, we send a duplicate vertex to restart a new strip for the next row (This can be omitted if j == numRows - 1)
    glVertex3fv(vertices + vertexOffset - vertexSize + nextRow);
}
```

If you are concerned about sending duplicate vertices you could use an additional index buffer, as that will allow you to use the exact same vertex buffer you used for the `GL_POINTS` version.

Comment: I've made some minor edits, and edited the code to match. Hopefully this leaves the answer as you intended it but feel free to revert anything that doesn't.